# How can I use VBA to separate data in a long column with occasional dates at the beginning of some rows?

Tags: excel, vba

VBA For Excel - Need to run a text to columns action for slightly different rows in the same column

[image]

Hi, I am trying to write a VBA script for separating some data that appears in long rows of text/numbers/dates, all in column A. For the most part the formats are all pretty similar, the only difference being that occasionally some of the rows have a date at the beginning and the rest do not, so I need the script to differentiate between these, and move the date to column A if it is there, and if not then just leave the column blank and place the next data in column B, then column C, etc.

Could anyone help with this please? Attached are examples of the rows to be worked upon in column A, with the desired output being 14 columns in total show also.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: What is separating the data? Have you tried using (and then recording) Data>Text-to-Columns?

Comment: Looks to me as Text-to-Columns with fixed with (not with separator) should do the trick for you.

Comment: Hi thanks for responding @CLR - the data pieces are separated by spaces, and I believe it is the same number of spaces each time, the only difference being the number of spaces on the rows that contain a date at the start of them, but thereafter they are identical to the other rows.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding @FunThomas - I take it the fixed width approach would work quite well with the specific spaces between the data pieces? My main problem I suppose is how to frame this so that it can work around the situation of there being two different row types?

Comment: Are those really different row types? Looks to me as if the row without leading date has spaces instead, so that the 2nd column starts at the same position (12, I guess)

Answer (score 0):

try and modify accordingly

looking at your sample data it looks like the delimiter are several spaces between values and some are different number of spaces, the code below assumes the common delimiter is 3 spaces and if there are delimiters that are more than 3 spaces there will be blank cells after the split so I added to check blank cells in the range and delete it

```
Sub SplitText()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lastrow As Long, lastcol As Long, n As Long
    Dim rng As Range, blankCells As Range
    Dim MyArray() As String, Count As Long, i As Variant
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") 'modify accordingly
    lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For n = 1 To lastrow
        'assumes delimiter as 3 blank spaces
        MyArray = Split(ws.Cells(n, 1), "   ") 'modify delimiter accordingly
        Count = 1
        For Each i In MyArray
            ws.Cells(n, Count) = i
            Count = Count + 1
        Next i
        If Not IsDate(ws.Cells(n, 1)) Then ws.Cells(n, 1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Next n
    
    'delete blank cells in the range after split excluding colum A
    lastcol = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set rng = ws.Range("B1", ws.Cells(lastrow, lastcol))
    Set blankCells = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    If Not blankCells Is Nothing Then
        blankCells.Delete xlToLeft
    End If
    
End Sub
```